# No value has been specified for property 'imageId' while creating container

Tags: gradle, docker, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am new to docker and using bmuschko plugin in gradle to create docker image, container and run it. Only buildImage task seems to work. When creating a container it says

> No value has been specified for property 'imageId'

Here is my gradle file snippet.

```
dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:2.6.5'
    }
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.*
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.*

task copyJar(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn   'jar'
    from        'build/libs/rest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    into        'build/docker'

    from        'src/main/resources/Dockerfile'
    into        'build/docker'
}

task buildImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    dependsOn 'copyJar'
    inputDir = file('build/docker');
    url = 'unix:///var/run/docker.sock'
    tag = 'rest-app/nci:0.1'
}

task createContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    dependsOn buildImage
    containerName = 'my-rest-app'
    targetImageId { buildImage.getImageId() }
    portBindings = ['8080:8080']
}

task startContainer(type: DockerStartContainer) {
    dependsOn createContainer
    targetContainerId { createContainer.getContainerId()}
}

build.dependsOn copyJar
build.dependsOn buildImage
build.dependsOn createContainer
```

Here is the stacktrace snippet.

> .....
>   rest-app:check :rest-app:createContainer ID !!!!!!!8cf8fc8d2af9
>   :rest-app:createContainer FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem was found with the configuration of task
>   ':rest-app:createContainer'.
>
> No value has been specified for property 'imageId'. Try: Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskValidationException: A problem
>   was found with the configuration of task ':rest-app:createContainer'.
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:55)

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not familiar with Gradle, but judging by the error message, it looks like you haven't specified an image ID. Aren't you supposed to give a base image upon which you build up your own image?

Comment: @Pubudu thanks for your reply. Since it has `targetImageId { buildImage.getImageId() }` it is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue. Seems like the functionality i.e. `targetImageId(...)` does not work as expected. So downgrading from 2.6.6 to 2.6.5 works like a charm. Here is the [bug created and answered](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/issues/171) in their official github website.

Comment: Seems like this functionality works well for the new release i.e. 2.6.7.